# How can I update the state of objects within an array using React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the best practice in React to push a new object to an array within an object that doesn't have a key and then have the state update? I'm currently able to update it, but it's mutating the state which I know is not a best practice. I'd like to be able to use `this.setState` so my component re-renders. Thanks!

```
currentState = {
    lorem: [
        {
            id: 123,
            title: 'quis nostrud'
            ipsum: [
                {
                    dolor: 0,
                    amet: 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 456,
            title: 'occaecat cupidatat'
            ipsum: [
                {
                    dolor: 0,
                    amet: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

desiredState = {
    lorem: [
        {
            id: 123,
            title: 'quis nostrud'
            ipsum: [
                {
                    dolor: 0,
                    amet: 0
                },
                {
                    dolor: 100,
                    amet: 100
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 456,
            title: 'occaecat cupidatat'
            ipsum: [
                {
                    dolor: 0,
                    amet: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you can solve your problem by using this.setState differently.
this.setState(prevState => { 
  // drive your newState from prevState after cloning it
  return newState;
})

Comment: I looked into that, but it seemed like I still needed to know which object's array needs to be updated. Do you have an example that you think would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code from @gdh above which was overwriting the lorem object with the new ipsum array.

Here is a working example that instead appends the new object to the correct ipsum array within the lorem object: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-k8kpo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should not mutate the original state directly. You need to find the id of which object you need to update in the array then update the state.

**Like this**

```js
const updatedLorem = currentState.lorem.map(x => {
    if(x.id === '123') // <----- you will need to know which id to update
        return [...x.ipsum, {dolor: 0, amet: 0}]
    else
        return x
})

this.setState(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    lorem: updatedLorem
}))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for the help. I may be over looking something, but when I set the state at the end wouldn't it need to be something along the lines of `lorem[desiredObject]['ipsum']: updatedLorem`?

Comment: this replaces the first lorem array item with the new ipsum array rather than spreading it into the complete object

Comment: @JonB That is what I'm experiencing.